# Htaccess Redirect to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Hi guys I am having trouble redirecting to another page of my test site and passing the variables through to it.

This is my link

```
<a href="/dashboard/add_social.html?id=<?=$social_platform->getId()?>&action=delete" class="delete">delete</a>
```

This is the `Rewrite Rule` in the `htaccess` file but it does not seem to be working. I'm sure I've done it wrong so I'd appreciate any help.

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/add_social.html\.html$                   pages/dashboard/smr_add_social.dashboard.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Not the answer to your problem - but is this a delete link? if so - might be wise to consider a different mechanism. Links are often pre-fetched by some ISPs and browsers and you could start having content disappearing on you...

Comment: Yes, It calls a controller page that will either edit, delete or activate the item in the list

Comment: Ever wondered what `$1` did? ;-) I bet that if you remove `?id=$1` it magically starts working.

Comment: I removed the `?id=$1` but still no luck

Comment: @steve Not to mention an exploit where an user without permission can lure an user with permission into deleting something with an image-that-is-actually-a-redirect on, for example, a forum. That's why admin actions should always be POST-requests.

Comment: Precisely... although I'm not helping with the question pointing this out I guess :)

Comment: Of course your rule did not match, because you had `.html\.html` at the end of the pattern …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `/.html`

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/add_social.html$  pages/dashboard/smr_add_social.dashboard.php [QSA,L]
```

And do note that the `QSA` flag means that if there's a query string passed it will be appended to the new url.

Comment: Although that is correct, this wasn’t actually the issue here – OP _had_ that flag already set. The pattern did not match, because it had `.html\.html` at the end of it …

Comment: Seeing how he was using it I really do not think the OP understood the flag, hence the explanation. The /.html is pretty self explanatory. But I'll agree that the answer might be confusing, i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

1. fix wrong rewrite rule "^dashboard/add_social.html.html$"
2. for transfer _GET parameters to another script by ModRewrite need use `%{QUERY_STRING}`

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^dashboard/add_social.html$     pages/dashboard/smr_add_social.dashboard.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]